# Accessing WPF component inside DataTemplate with Data Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have several UI elements in a `DataTemplate` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of Video objects. I want to call a method of a Video object when I click on the ContextMenuItem [Test] of the corresponding UI element.

Here is my XAML:

```
            <ItemsControl Name="VideoUIElment" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Uid="videoTemplate">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Padding="10, 10" Background="Silver" >
                            <TextBlock Name="label" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="[TEST]" Name="Test" Click="Test_Click"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>                              
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Here is the collection:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        //ctor
        InitializeComponent();
        pathToLauncher = string.Empty;
        videos = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
        VideoUIElment.ItemsSource = videos;
    }
```

I know that, to do this, **I have to identify which Video object inside the collection is bound to the specific UI element I click on**, and I could come up with some trick to achieve this, but I would like to do it in a graceful and intelligent way.
I've seen some suggestions already, but none of them seemed to have been applicable here. I guess, it is supposed to be something easy, but I'm not very versed in WPF yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Video> videos { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        videos = new ObservableCollection<Video>
        {
            new Video {Name = "Video 1"},
            new Video {Name = "Video 2"},
            new Video {Name = "Video 3"}
        };

        VideoUIElment.ItemsSource = videos;
    }

    private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;

        Video video = (Video)item.DataContext;

        MessageBox.Show(video.VideoMethod());
    }
}
```

**Video:**

```
public class Video
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string VideoMethod()
    {
        return string.Format(" Clicked {0}", Name);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So it's always the innermost element (in my case it's the MenuItem) that raises the event?

Comment: Note you're explicitly responding to the `Click` event of the `MenuItem` as per your XAML. So, it is not necessarily always the inner most but from where the event is coming, depending on your particular XAML.

Comment: Oh, of course, it was too early in the morning for me. Thank you for your help!